How do I learn from/for whom is this German textbook intended?
I studied German in school more than 20 years ago.  I remember quite a few words and the general idea of how to put a sentence together.  Now I would like to pick up my studies again as an adult.  I picked up this book at a used book store and it seems to be a good match.  I was able to breeze through the first chapter or two without too much difficulty.
I noticed, however, that unlike any other foreign language text I've seen, it is entirely printed in German.  I was expecting English explanations, instructions, or even an introduction to the text.
I must be missing something.   Once I get beyond the little German I remember, is it intended that I will learn the language only through context and looking at the pictures? As an aside, what audience was this book aimed at?

It's a „Kursbuch“ meant to be used in a language course with a teacher. It's not meant for self-study. This kind of book is very common in Germany for language learning. All our school books for foreign languages are like that.

@Janka would it be used by German speakers or speakers of other languages?

The book cover says "Deutsch als Fremdsprache"  which means "German as a foreign language".

It's for non-German speakers. The teacher is supposed to give you additional advice about everything not covered by the book. If you are self-learning, you want a book intented for learning without a teacher instead.

So it would likely be used in Germany, at school, by kids who don't speak German.  And it presumes that their teacher also speaks their native language?

For people who don’t want to follow a link to Amazon US, this is about “Themen aktuell” by Hueber. https://www.hueber.de/themen-aktuell

@nuggethead, I do not think that this is primarily for teaching children.

This book, Themen aktuell, consisting of three volumes, seems to be directed at adults having to pass the Deutsch-Test für Zuwanderer, the obligatory language certification needed for immigrants to aquire the right to a permanent residency in Germany. This guide describes the relationship between the book and the exam in detail.
The book is not meant to be used for self-study, but in a Intergrationskurs, the courses about living in Germany immigrants are expected to take part in, and with a teacher in front of a class. Also, it is meant to be used by students that are already living in a German-speaking environment, to help them to quickly start to communicate on the street, or to understand the news, or letters sent by German authorities.
The level of knowledge covered by the three volumes corresponds to the Common European Framework of Reference for Languages and its levels A1, A2 and B1 (the last one being the level for the certification).
It seems the books are also in use in Austria for the Österreichisches Sprachdiplom Deutsch.

Upvoted, but I don’t think that this is exclusively for immigrants working towards a specific test.
Also, there is a six volume edition corresponding to A1/2, B1/2, C1/2. But this isn’t Hueber’s PR department here, so that’s not really important.

You have to part with the idea of learning a language by translation. This book is not for that.
Think about how you learned your mother tongue. It was by hearing, accumulating words and sentence structures, repeating. (All that unconsciencly.) This book mimics that learning process, supported by a teacher (and to some degree by the other pupils in the learning group) whose primary role is not to explain but to exercise and correct, just like your parents did, when you were a toddler learning to speak.
Often foreign language learners are very scared that they will not get support/instructions in their mother tongue. They think that will help them, but in fact what happens is that it trains you to think in in your mother tongue and than translate. That is not only slow, but also

So if I can manage to figure it out with this book, it will be a somewhat more immersive experience and I may learn the language better/deeper because it won't be "connected" to English?

The last part of you sentence got lost: "…slow, but also …" - error prone?

@nuggethead Yes, that is the idea, but it is pretty difficult doing it only with the book. A teacher, although he would also not speak other than in German, is of help.
If you want to do it without help, but also with a book not containing a single word other than German, I would recommend you "Deutsch für Ausländer" from Hermann Kessler. First edition somewhere in the 1930s, last at the end of the 1980s. (Than Kessler was bought by Hueber and they never published the books again. They eliiminated a competitor.)
Archive.org has it:
https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.259926/

@nuggethead Continued:
https://archive.org/details/dli.ernet.259927
https://archive.org/details/deutschfrausl00kess
Take the first link (from the other comment), that is the beginners book. Unfortunately the only page where color matters (the first one) is also in black and white. (The rest of the book is not colored.) But you will figure it out.
Pls. give feedback, about what you think of the book and its method.
